# TortoiseSVN Plugin: mark color/tag beside a version

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a possibility or plug-in available for [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) to mark the checked out source with different colors depending on the SVN source? Would be useful to distinguish versions for development/testing/release or different customers.

Comment: What do you mean with "DEV/SIT/UAT/PROD"?

Comment: @Kosi2801: Excellent edit, now it even got up-voted :)

Comment: Thanks. Had to read and think several times until I found out what was really meant ;) I hope it really matches the intents of the author.

Comment: Thanks, it's what i really intend to express

Comment: On what basis should they be distinguished by plug-in? Using some svn property?